# sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, kubernetes

To make sure that all pods should have certain security settings applied uniformly, i made changes in my yaml file as follows:

```
securityContext:
            runAsUser: 20001
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - "ALL"
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```

This is my dockerfile -

```
RUN groupadd npsuser -g 10001
RUN useradd -u 20001 -g 10001 -o npsuser
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/npsuser_sudo_for_me
RUN chmod u+x /bin/sudo

USER npsuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sudo","-E","/bin/local-nztmps-csi-driver"]
```

but i am getting the following error -

```
[root@comfort1 local-csi-plugin]# oc logs -f pod/local-nztmpfs-csi-node-pnrl5 -n kube-system
Defaulted container "nzlocal-plugin" out of: nzlocal-plugin, node-driver-registrar, liveness-probe
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Why set a (non-root) user and then set the entrypoint to sudo?!

Answer (score 0):

Delete almost everything you show in the question.  Don't install `sudo` in your image.  If the main container process needs to run as root, specify that as the `USER` instead

```bash
USER root
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/local-nztmps-csi-driver"]
```

The setup you show here looks like you're trying to pretend to be a non-root user, but then use `sudo` to run your process as root anyways.  The security controls don't allow that (possibly because you've given up the `CAP_SETGID` Linux capability).  If your process needs to be root, it's much easier to just run as root; if you need additional permissions from the cluster to do that, you should work with your cluster administrator to get an appropriate setup.